# How to fix loop that checks whether Scanner has another line of input?

Tags: java, file-io, io

My file program works fine. It creates a txt file with the contents I submitted. But, why does my console display 'true' infinitely?

[image]

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What would you like the file to be called?");
        String output = input.nextLine();

        if (!output.contains(".txt")) {
            output += ".txt";
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(output);
        System.out.println("What would you like to print to the file? ");
        String fileContents = input.nextLine();
        out.print(fileContents);
        out.close();

        Scanner fromFile = new Scanner(new File(output));

        System.out.println("The File " + output + " contains: ");

        while (fromFile.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(fromFile.hasNextLine());
        }

        System.out.println("Finished reading and writing from file.. ");
        input.close();
        fromFile.close();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not actually retrieving the next line

```
while (fromFile.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(fromFile.hasNextLine());
}
```

Your print statement is simply re-checking that it has a newline.  I think what you meant to do was

```
System.out.println(fromFile.nextLine());
```

By calling nextLine() you are telling Scanner that you want to consume all the characters up to the next `'\n'` (newline) character.  See the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually get a line inside the loop, otherwise it will report that there is a next (first) line.